# Datagridview sum of same identical rows

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, sum

I have a sql table basicly like this :

[image]

As you can see, there is data which uses same ProductID(1002 and 1004). My expectation of this table to become summed and merged with the rows of same ProductID.

[image]

I'm using c# and dataGridView. Can we sum those values via sql query then load it onto dataGridView ? or I must create a if - for etc.. statements to check & sum dataGridView rows ?

Edit :

For David's answer :

```
   select * from tblOrderDetail where OrderID in 
   (select OrderID from tblOrders whereCustomerID = 231234)

 // Select * at start gets the ProductID and Quantity
```

How I can add your solution to this ? when I tried couple things I had errors about using "in" Clause.

Comment: What was the error that you got?  And how does this NEW question of yours (which maybe you should ask as a new question) relate to the original one?

Comment: Error is "Column tblOrderDetail.OrderDetailID is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." Actually I asked this question for this query. I just tried to make it look simple and easier to get with it.

Comment: So, any columns in tblOrderDetail that are NOT part of what you're adding up need to go into the GROUP BY clause.  If this isn't clear, then please post what the columns actually are.

Comment: @DavidWallace It's obviously part of the table. I'm getting this error because I'm not used to syntax of sql query language or whatever it is. I'll try different approach on syntax. Thanks for SUM function. Much appreciated.

Comment: So, anything that's in what you're selecting, other than the part that you're adding up, needs to be listed next to GROUP BY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT   productID, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM     myTable
GROUP BY productID
```

Comment: When I try this code solely like this, it works but can we arrange this method to my query ? I updated my question.

Comment: David can we use Select *, instead of ProductID ?

Comment: It's best not to use select * because you want to be able to specify which columns get added up, and which ones don't.  List the columns that you actually need.